# async method not working in android background service xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, background-process

i am using following code

```
public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}


public static int ConvertMinutesToMilliseconds(int minutes)
{
    return (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).TotalMilliseconds;
}
System.Threading.Timer _timer;
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    DoWork();
    _timer = new System.Threading.Timer((o) => {
      SyncStepsToApi();
    }, null, 0, 20000);

    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}


public async void SyncStepsToApi()
        {
            SaveEmployeeActivities saveEmployeeActivities = new SaveEmployeeActivities();

            saveEmployeeActivities.AuthenticationToken = APICalling.authToken;
            saveEmployeeActivities.Steps =await db.GetUserSteps();
           var numberOfActivitiesModified= await ServiceClient.SaveUserActivity(saveEmployeeActivities);
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.screen)
          .SetContentTitle("perkit service notification")
          .SetContentText(numberOfActivitiesModified.NoOfActivitiesModified.ToString());

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(19000, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
```

to run a service background, everything is working fine except `SyncStepsToApi();` this method is calling only when app remains on foreground.
when i close the app service works fine except, in syncsteptoapi (db.getusersteps) returns 0 records.

Comment: Are you using a foregrounded `Service`?...

Comment: but i need this service to work while app is closed. or in background.

Comment: A foregrounded service is "totally" different then a backgrounded app. And also I am assuming that `GetUserSteps` is totally independent of any UI

Comment: thanks for response, ill look into it, and yes 'GetUserSteps'  is independent of any UI